# How to fix server IP address could not be found when trying to reach a raspberry Pi from the internet?

Tags: raspberry-pi, webserver

I am trying to set my raspberry pi as a web server just to play around. 
I changed the DNS record of my domain to point to my IP address. 
then I forwarded the requests of port 80 to my raspberry pi internal IP address from the router. 
I can reach the raspberry pi from my internal wifi connection using its ip address. However, I can't reach it using my domain name. I am getting this " server IP address could not be found." error. 
Tried to clean cashe from chrome, and tried another browser ..etc. didn't work. 
Any Ideas?

EDIT: ping works and no packages are lost
+
I waited 2 days already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing DNS it will take some time before all nameservers get changes.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/domain-names/dns-nameserver-changes/domain-names-dns-changes)

You can try and go to your public IP. Then you should be able to visit your webserver, if you have forwarded it correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Check out my edit: ping works  and going directly to my IP works as well

Comment: actually your comment led me to the solution. 
The mistake I did was in the A records. 
I had to add "@" in the host field. 
it's really sad that this is not mentioned anywhere when they teach you about DNS records.

Comment: What DNS provider are you using?

Comment: sorry I just saw your comment now. I am using namecheap